# selecting DB value before report main dataset

Tags: jasper-reports

I have built a report that is a list of values related to a specific date.

The report consists of four subreports share the same main header data. So, the main dataset reads data for the main header.

I have successfully assigned a date prompt parameter so the user can select the desired date of the list. This parameter is passed to the main dataset to read main header data. This parameter_date is passed to subreports to display details data.

Everything is working excellent.

I want me report to be more dynamic. If the user didn't select date, I want the report to display data for the latest date added to DB.

I uses mySQL; so; select max(data_date) from data_table is fine with me. But how can I make the report reads this value and pass it to the main dataset as if the user select it in the first place?

I only use jasper studio to build reports. I don't know how to program using Java.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

well, I found a solution for my specific challenge as follows :

```
SELECT
    data_date
FROM
    . . .
WHERE 
     data_date = case when $P{selected_date} is null then
        ( select max(data_date) from . . . )
     else
        $P{selected_date}
     end;
```

hope this will help someone

take care